# Get Details of object in angular 6

Tags: angular

What I'm trying to do is If i click a coursemodule, it will display its details. I have this code already and it gives an error: **Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**.

**coursemoduleapi.service.ts**

```
getCourseModule(id:number) {
return this.httpClient.get(`${this.baseUrl}${id}/`, {headers: this.headers}); 
}
```

**coursemodule.component.ts**

```
export class CoursemoduleComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() coursemodule;

coursemodules: any = []
selectedCourseModule = null;

constructor(
private coursemoduleService: CoursemoduleapiService
) { }

ngOnInit() {

this.coursemoduleService.getCourseModules().subscribe(
  data => {
    this.coursemodules = data;
  },
  error => console.log(error)
 );

}

getDetails() {
this.coursemoduleService.getCourseModule(this.coursemodule.id).subscribe(
  coursemodule => {
    console.log(coursemodule);
  },
  error => console.log(error)
 );
 }

}
```

**coursemodule.component.html**

```
<app-coursemodule-list [coursemodules]="coursemodules"
(getDetails)="getDetails($event)"> </app-coursemodule-list>
```

**coursemodule-list.component.ts**

```
export class CoursemoduleListComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() coursemodules = [];
@Output() getDetails = new EventEmitter();

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {}

courseModuleClicked(coursemodule) {
this.getDetails.emit(coursemodule)
}
```

**coursemodule-list.component.html**

```
<div class="list-group list-group-flush" role="tablist"  
*ngFor="let coursmodule of coursemodules">
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data- 
    toggle="list" href="#account" role="tab" 
    (click)=courseModuleClicked(coursmodule_id)>
        {{coursmodule.coursemodule_title}}
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You have `@Input() coursemodule;`. Where is the data being input from?

Comment: @abney317 I'm trying to use it as a parameter for the coursemodule.id which is im trying to get from (click)=courseModuleClicked(coursmodule_id). But its saying id is undefined.

Comment: `id is undefined` because there is no such property, "id" in each item of your array of coursemodule objects. Do a `console.log(coursemodules)` in your ngOnInit(){} and you should know where to fix your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly the `coursemodules` input is not getting any value from the parent component. There seems to be typo in the parameter name in the click method.

In your code it is `courseModuleClicked(coursmodule_id)` changing it to `courseModuleClicked(coursmodule.id)` should make it work

Comment: Thanks @Karthick this also did the trick. I also added a parameter for my getDetails function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got it to work, I added a parameter for on getDetails function and was able to get it on my console log.

**coursemodule.component.ts**

```
getDetails(coursemodule) {
this.coursemoduleService.getCourseModule(coursemodule).subscribe(
coursemodule => {
console.log(coursemodule);
  },
error => console.log(error)
);
}
```

In my **coursemodule-list.component.html**
I changed the parameter for the click function to coursemodule.id which now looks like this:

```
(click)=courseModuleClicked(coursmodule.id)
```